# Referencing PCL library from ASP.NET 5 in Visual Studio 2015 Preview doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I'm playing around with the new ASP.NET MVC 6 in Visual Studio 2015 Preview, when I try to add a reference to Instasharp 2-beta7 (it's a portable library) I get a warning sign under References for that library. Is this something that hasn't been addressed yet in VS2015 preview? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same setup as you. I just added a reference to the version you mentioned and I am not getting any warnings under references. Perhaps try adding it again, or trying with a new empty project.

Comment: Are you using MVC-6 on VS2015 Preview? I just created a new Starter Web project, and added "InstaSharp":  "2.0.0-beta7" to project.json and I still have the same problem.

Comment: It took a bit but it looks like it was just downloading the other dependencies. It's all good now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am using that. See the [screenshot](http://picpaste.com/Capture-yqG4KJdG.PNG) here --- I see it worked now :)